# iterate over array parameter in object

Tags: angular, observable, ngfor

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[{
  position: "Software Developer",
  company: "Big company",
  details: [
    "task1","task2,"task3"
  ]
},
{
  position: "Software Developer",
  company: "Another Big company",
  details: [
    "task1a","task2a,"task3a"
  ]
}]
```

I read that from the service in my component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getExperience().subscribe(
      data => this.experience$ = data
    )
  }
```

In my html I iterate over this array but inside the loop I would like to iterate over details as well. I've tried a few approaches including the below one but I don't really understand how that works here. How to approach it correctly?

```
<li *ngFor='let experience of experience$'>
    <!--<a routerLink='/details/{{ user.id }}'>{{ user.name }}</a>-->
    <ul>
      <li class="position">{{ experience.position }}</li>
      <!--<li><a href='http://{{ user.website }}'>{{ user.website }}</a></li>-->
      <li class="company">{{ experience.company}}<span class="dates">  {{ experience.dates}}</span></li>
      <ul class="details" *ngFor='let d of experience.details$'></ul>
        <li>{{ d }}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is generally suffixed after a property name if that property contains an Observable value. This is done as a naming convention as stated in the [**Angular Guide here**](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#naming-conventions-for-observables):

> Because Angular applications are mostly written in TypeScript, you will typically know when a variable is an observable. Although the Angular framework does not enforce a naming convention for observables, you will often see observables named with a trailing “$” sign.
>
> This can be useful when scanning through code and looking for observable values. Also, if you want a property to store the most recent value from an observable, it can be convenient to simply use the same name with or without the “$”.

Since you're already `subscribing` to the Observable and the `experience$` won't be an Observable and instead it would be an array, you should consider naming the property differently.

Try this without the $.

The `li` for details is also not in the `ul`. So fix it by doing the following:

```
<li *ngFor='let experience of experiences'>
  <!--<a routerLink='/details/{{ user.id }}'>{{ user.name }}</a>-->
  <ul>
    <li class="position">{{ experience.position }}</li>
    <!--<li><a href='http://{{ user.website }}'>{{ user.website }}</a></li>-->
    <li class="company">{{ experience.company}}<span class="dates">  {{ experience.dates}}</span></li>
    <ul class="details" *ngFor='let d of experience.details'>
      <li>{{ d }}</li>
    </ul>

  </ul>
</li>
```

Also make this change in your Component Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  experiences: any[];

  constructor(private data: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getExperience().subscribe(
      data => this.experiences = data
    )
  }
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-data-and-display-in-ul-and-li?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: I tried this and get "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" on the elements that has details (for object with no details code works fine)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo just remove the `$` after `details`. Also, do not use `$` for non-observable variable, as this naming convention is usually used to identify observables.

```
<li *ngFor='let experience of experience$'>
    <!--<a routerLink='/details/{{ user.id }}'>{{ user.name }}</a>-->
    <ul>
      <li class="position">{{ experience.position }}</li>
      <!--<li><a href='http://{{ user.website }}'>{{ user.website }}</a></li>-->
      <li class="company">{{ experience.company}}<span class="dates">  {{ experience.dates}}</span></li>
      <ul class="details" *ngFor='let d of experience.details'></ul>
        <li>{{ d }}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the convention, it's changed :) About the solution: please check my comments for the answer above yours.